# Rendering separate components in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering, render

I am trying to render components on the screen, in a top down kind of behavior.

**Code:**

```
render() {
    this.renderFirstComp(); // stuff in the header
    this.renderSecondComp();
    this.renderThirdComp();

    if(some condition){
        return( <Text> something </Text>)
    }
    else {
        return( <Text> something else </Text>)
    }
}

renderFirstComp() {
    let tests = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

    return(
        <View>
            <Text> Test #: </Text>
            <Text>{tests[this.state.selectedTest]} </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

renderSecondComp(){
    return .....;
}

renderThirdComp(){
    return .....;
}
```

But this routine is not working (nothing is getting rendered). Am I following the right pattern?

**Edit:** 
I want to render all the above: FirstComp, Sec, Third.. **and** the stuff inside the if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issues:

**1.** You are not returning anything from `render` method, only the functions are returning the elements.

**2.** You can't return more than one element from `render` method, so you need to wrap them inside a `div`.

Use this:

```
render() {
   return(
      <div>
          {this.renderFirstComp()}

          {this.renderSecondComp()}

          {this.renderThirdComp()}

          {
             condition ? <Text> something </Text> : <Text> something else </Text>           
          }
      </div>
   )
}
```

**Another possible way:**

Use the variables to save the element returned by the functions and render those variables, like this:

```
render() {
    let first = this.renderFirstComp();
    let second = this.renderSecondComp();
    let third = this.renderThirdComp();
    let additionalElement = this._renderAdditionalElement()
    return(
        <div>
            {first}
            {second}
            {third}
            {additionalElement}
        </div>
    )
}

_renderAdditionalElement(){
    if(true){
        return( <Text> something </Text>) 
    }else{
        return( <Text> something else </Text>)
    }
}
```

Comment: check the updated answer, when you call the function it will render the returned elements and use the condition to render the additional element or you can use the same pattern call a function and put the condition inside that and return the element.

Comment: We got it fixed by changing `div` to `View` since I am not on the web, I am on Mobile App